Locking down my parent's Windows 11 computer to keep it clean and fresh and fast
My mom uses a PC every day but isn't tech savvy. 80% of what she does is use Chrome. But she also uses Office (e.g. Word) and Firefox.
My dad and I want to lock Windows 11 down so that she:

Is not an admin (obviously, we've never let her have an admin user account).
Can't change any other settings (I'm not sure what non-admins can change, but she'd find a way).
Is unable to save files anywhere other than a USB drive.

We don't want her saving files to random places like the desktop, Documents folder, root C: drive, etc.
We want to be guaranteed that anything she'd ever care about would always be all in just one place (with subfolders if she wants).
I've recently heard of Deep Freeze, but it doesn't sound exactly like what I'm looking for.
Windows 11's built-in multi-app kiosk mode looks interesting but is probably only a partial solution.
Ideas?

You're asking for a pretty broad set of solutions, given the requirements you've given. Given that my professional career is managing locked down devices for enterprises, Windows seems to run against the really locked down feature you want right now. Frankly, a Chromebook or similar is likely to be a better option, or you or your dad just commit to weekly cleanups of your mom's PC.

Consider an OS other than Windows which can be booted from a finalized DVD or CD (Live DVD) or other read-only media, such as a SD card with switch set to read-only. The internal SSD or HDD can serve for storage, or a USB drive could be used, as you suggest.
Some operating systems that could be used:

Ubuntu
Fedora
One of the many other alternatives

My relatives who've used Windows since v. 3.1 through Windows 10 have had no trouble switching over, and find native apps, such as Firefox, Thunderbird and LibreOffice, easy to use.

+1 because I had that idea too. Unfortunately my parents rejected it. They refuse to use anything but Windows.
